# WPF ValidationRule Success Message

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, validationrules

I know how in WPF application to make an error message using ValidationRule, by defining it in ErrorTemplate tag when ValidationResult is false. My question is there any way to make message when ValidationResult is true?

Answer (score 0):

You could do what you want in your own validationrule.
If you look at:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.validationrule%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

```
else
{
    // show a message box or something
    return new ValidationResult(true, null);
}
```

You may well find there are some unwanted side effects if you do something blocking and maybe you don't just mean show a message.

When the validationrule decides a value fails, it stops the value transferring to the source ( the property on the viewmodel ).
You could therefore drive some processing from the setter of a bound property in your viewmodel.
You could alternatively handle sourceupdated and set notifysourceupdated on your binding. Do something with that as a generic approach.